# SELECT Conditions not being met

Tags: sql

I need a query that brings back the appointments within the date criteria OR if the hc_id matches what I give it and the stop_date is NULL, I want it to come back regardless. My query now works for most of my situations, except when the stop_date is NULL, then nothing is brought back.

I can't get my OR statements working like I think they should in my head.

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.appt_type_id, r.frequency, r.frequency_type, r.frequency_data, r.start_date, r.end_date, r.stop_date as 'stop_recurring'
        FROM appt_recurring r
        WHERE r.hc_id = :hc_id
        AND (r.start_date >= :start_date
        OR r.stop_date >= :end_date)
        OR r.stop_date = NULL
        ORDER BY r.start_date ASC
```

This brings me back appointments only that match the first AND line on line 4 without any regard to parenthetical placement or the lines afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`= NULL` always fails.  I think you want:

```
WHERE r.hc_id = :hc_id AND
      r.start_date >= :start_date AND
      (r.stop_date >= :end_date OR
       r.stop_date IS NULL
      )
```